# Rename Columns in query from another table result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two table. A contains the data and B contains the columns explanation for A

```
Select * from tableA
```

```
|ID | A | B | C |
|---|---|---|---|
|1  | ? | ? | ? |
|2  | ? | ? | ? |
|3  | ? | ? | ? |
|4  | ? | ? | ? |
|5  | ? | ? | ? |
```

```
Select * from tableB
```

```
|col|  Desc  |
|---|--------|
|A  | Value1 |
|B  | Value2 |
|C  | Value3 |
```

The result I would like to get

```
|ID | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 |
|---|--------|--------|--------|
|1  |    ?   |    ?   |    ?   |
|2  |    ?   |    ?   |    ?   |
|3  |    ?   |    ?   |    ?   |
|4  |    ?   |    ?   |    ?   |
|5  |    ?   |    ?   |    ?   |
```

Is there anyway to rename the columns with script instead using the following code? Because the columns are more than 40 and I have several tables to be converted into view, it is not a good practice for creating and maintain the view

```
Select A as Value1, B as Value2, C as Value3 From TableA
```

I tried to use the different key words to google it however the result are all rename it by manually. Maybe it's because I am using the wrong key words

Thanks in advance

Comment: From what you describe, you will need to use Dynamic SQL. But how did you get into this scenario in the first place ?

Comment: @Squirrel My company is using Oracle product. I got the DB right few days ago after my colleague resign. I think this naming structure is for the covering sensitive data and for the naming consistency~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to form the `Dynamic Query` and than execute it using `sp_executesql`

---

```
DECLARE @sql    NVARCHAR(MAX);
    
SELECT  @sql = STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(col) + ' AS ' + QUOTENAME([Desc]), ',')
FROM    tableB;

SELECT  @sql = 'SELECT ID, '
             + @sql 
             + ' FROM tableA';
PRINT   @sql;
EXEC    sp_executesql @sql;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @Squirrel's ans first. However `STRING_AGG` is not compatible to TSQL.

The way I solve is somehow like him.

```
DECLARE @query    NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @sql    NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @sql = COALESCE(@sql + ',', '') + col + ' AS ' + QUOTENAME(DESCR)
FROM    tableB;

SELECT  @query= 'SELECT ' + @sql + ' FROM tableA';

PRINT(@query);
EXEC(@query);
```